# Is it possible to run an android emulator, get image files of its state, and emulate mouse function with it from a headless linux server?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-emulator, emulation, headless

**If what I ask in the *'Questions'* section can't be done, then the rest of this post is moot. Look at that first so you don't waste your time reading the background I provided if it turns out to be impossible.**

### Questions

My server is an AWS m4.large running headless Ubuntu. As far as I am aware, it does not have a GPU, although I have RDP'd into it in the past in order to do something that needed a GUI. Before anything else, I have a few questions about whether certain things are possible:

- It seems to be possible to run an android emulator on a headless linux server, but is it possible to run an app with graphics despite not having a GPU?
- (If so) is it possible to get an image file out of what the emulator is currently showing?
- (If so) is it possible to emulate mouse functions based on X/Y coordinates despite it being run headlessly?

### Work Done So Far

I'm currently trying to create an API for a mobile game that doesn't have one. So far, I have a clunky prototype written in Python (running on my Windows PC) that does the following *(When the code starts, the app is open to a scrollable list of users in a "guild")*:

1. Grabs a screenshot of the android emulator running the game
2. Searches the image for certain predefined "template" images (player names in the list)
3. Clicks on its location if the template is seen (opens player's stat page)
4. Uses OCR to read information on the page
5. Returns to the list and repeats from Step 2
6. If no templates are found, the program scrolls down and then repeats from Step 2
7. If all data from the predefined users is collected, the program ends

### Issues with my Prototype

- Python code must be run manually when the emulator running (and at the right page in the app)
- The PC can't be used while the code is running since it uses image parsing of screenshot and mouse functions
- It's not practical as an "API"

### Next Steps

If the things I mentioned in the 'Questions' section are possible, then the rest should just implementing the code from my prototype, and having it repeat on a schedule.

If anybody has ideas for accomplishing the same thing in an easier way, I'm absolutely open to suggestions.

Thanks for reading!